# Binding data in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to make simple WPF app with c# and I have following problem:
in my app I'm using class "Macierz" to represent and work with array of BigInteger objects. Now I need to graphically represent this array, using DataGrid (or something different if there is a better way to do this) and I have no idea how can I bound this DataGrid to my class. I had tried to do this by Data Sources window (VS 2013) but when I added my class to it my array didn't display.
Here is some code of my class:

```
public class Macierz
{
    public Macierz(ulong A, ulong B)
    {
        a = A;
        b = B;
        M = new BigInteger[A, B];
    }


    private ulong a, b;
    public ulong A
    {
        get
        {
            return a;
        }
    }

    public ulong B
    {
        get
        {
            return b;
        }
    }

    private BigInteger[,] M;

    public BigInteger this[ulong A, ulong B]
    {
        get
        {
            return M[A, B];
        }
        set
        {
            M[A, B] = value;
        }
    }
```

I need to represent in array with cells of textBoxes or something like that, so a user can easily change value of specific cell.

Edit:
Now, thanks to user3148019 answer I added this method in my class:

```
 public DataTable ToDataTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        DataRow tmp;
        for (ulong i = 0; i < b; i++)
            table.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(BigInteger));

        for (ulong i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            tmp = table.NewRow();
            for (ulong j = 0; j < b; j++)
                tmp[j.ToString()] = M[i, j];

            table.Rows.Add(tmp);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

so now I can show my array using DataGrid but this requires twice more memory and user can't change any values in original array. I tried to change my class replacing simple BigInteger[a, b] array with DataTable object but I have problem with accessing specific cells. For example:

```
public BigInteger tmp = 0;
for (ulong i = 0; i < a; i++)

            for (ulong j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                tmp += table.Rows[i].ItemArray[j];
            }
```

This generate errors:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataRowCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments
>   Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ulong' to 'int'

Is number of rows and columns in DataTable object limited to max of int or there is another way to access DataTable members?

Edit2:
I should say it earlier, that Macierz will never change any value inside array, so only user can change values of cell witch means I don't need INotifyCollectionChange (or maybe am I wrong?). Also now I think that showing full array is not always necessary. I don't want Macierz to derive from DependencyObject because I want to use it in other console application. I want to achieve my goal in simplest way. This is what I have now in Macierz:

```
 public DataTable ToDataTable(ulong AStart, ulong ACount, ulong BStart, ulong BCount)
    {
        if (AStart >= a)
            AStart = a - 1;
        if (BStart >= b)
            BStart = b - 1;

        ulong AStop = AStart + ACount;
        ulong BStop = BStart + BCount;

        if (AStop > a)
            AStop = a;
        if (BStop > b)
            BStop = b;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        DataRow tmp;
        BigInteger BItmp;

        for (ulong i = BStart; i < BStop; i++)
            table.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(BigInteger));
        table.Columns.Add("Suma", typeof(BigInteger));

        for (ulong i = AStart; i < AStop; i++)
        {
            tmp = table.NewRow();
            for (ulong j = BStart; j < BStop; j++)
                tmp[j.ToString()] = M[i, j];

            BItmp = 0;
            for (ulong j = 0; j < B; j++)
                BItmp += M[i, j];
            tmp["Suma"] = BItmp; 

            table.Rows.Add(tmp);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

and in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void PokazButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

        if (czyCala.IsChecked == true)
            GridTabela = M.ToDataTable(0, M.A, 0, M.B);
        else
            GridTabela = M.ToDataTable(VA, VACount, VB, VBCount);

        TabelaDataGrid.DataContext = this;
        TabelaDataGrid.ItemsSource = GridTabela.DefaultView;

        this.Cursor = null;
    }
```

This is working very well, allowing me to display array to user in easy way, but I don't now how to allow user change values in original array. I was trying to use CellEditEnding DataGrid event but I don't now how to access, read and validate input made by user in specific cell, especially how to get coordinates of that cell (I should probably get this information somehow like this "e.Column.something" or "e.Row.something" but I can't figure out how to do this).

Answer (score 1):

1. `Macierz` should derive from `DependencyObject`
2. you can't use multidimensional arrays for binding
3. use `ObservableCollection<>` instead of simple array
4. use `DependencyProperty` instead of simple data types
5. set the `DataContext` of your `DataGrid` to desired instance of `Macierz`

---

### EDIT:

The question you've asked is very general, to find a good answer I suggest you try this method and when you got the hang of it ask another question concerning other issues you may encounter. such as how to use ulong as ListSelector for an ObservableCollection, or how to add pages to an ItemsControl, or how to use a DataGrid with dynamic number of Columns.

Before I start I must say this answer only works for small size Macierz where both dimensions are int, and it becomes really slow for A*B > 10000.

The idea here is to create an `ItemsControl` which is a basic type of container used for displaying a `ObservableCollection`:

- `ItemsSource`: the source of the collection (which you bind to)
- `ItemTemplate`: the template of each item (how to display each item of the collection, I've used TextBlock (inside a Border) because it loads faster than TextBox)
- `ItemContainerStyle`: the style of each item's container. (`Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` must be set in the style provided within this member.)
- `ItemsPanel`: template of the panel of `itemsControl`. (I've used a `Grid` with dynamic number of rows and columns, and made use of a `GridHelper`)

Now you can have a single dimensional collection for M. The generic type of this collection should be equipped with `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` so that each element knows where in the `Grid` it belongs.

This is MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
InitializeComponent();
var mac = new Macierz(100,40);

//fill with test data
for (int i = 0; i < mac.A; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mac.B; j++)
    {
        mac[i, j].Data = string.Format("{0}...{1}", i, j);
    }
}

//set DataContext
this.DataContext = mac;
```

This is MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding M}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid local:GridHelper.RowCount="{Binding A}" 
                             local:GridHelper.ColumnCount="{Binding B}">
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is Macierz class:

```
public class Macierz : DependencyObject
{
    public Macierz(int A, int B)
    {
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
        for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < B; j++)
            {
                M.Add(new BigInteger(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    //A Dependency Property
    public int A
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(AProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(int), typeof(Macierz), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
    //B Dependency Property
    public int B
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(BProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(BProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(int), typeof(Macierz), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
    //Rows Observable Collection
    public ObservableCollection<BigInteger> M { get { return _m; } }
    private ObservableCollection<BigInteger> _m = new ObservableCollection<BigInteger>();

    public BigInteger this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return M[i * B + j]; }
        set { M[i * B + j] = value; }
    }
}
```

This is BigInteger class:

```
//replace this class with your own implementation.
//derive from DependencyObject and use DependencyProperty to store data
public class BigInteger : DependencyObject
{
    public BigInteger(int row, int col)
    {
        RowIndex = row;
        ColumnIndex = col;
    }
    //Data Dependency Property
    public string Data
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(string), typeof(BigInteger), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
    //RowIndex Dependency Property
    public int RowIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowIndexProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RowIndex", typeof(int), typeof(BigInteger), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
    //ColumnIndex Dependency Property
    public int ColumnIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnIndexProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnIndex", typeof(int), typeof(BigInteger), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

You also need a helper class. This is the simplified version of GridHelper. you can find the original class in [Rachel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel)'s [blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/):

```
public class GridHelper
{
    #region RowCount Property

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified number of Rows to RowDefinitions. 
    /// Default Height is Auto
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "RowCount", typeof(int), typeof(GridHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(-1, RowCountChanged));

    // Get
    public static int GetRowCount(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(RowCountProperty);
    }

    // Set
    public static void SetRowCount(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RowCountProperty, value);
    }

    // Change Event - Adds the Rows
    public static void RowCountChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(obj is Grid) || (int)e.NewValue < 0)
            return;

        Grid grid = (Grid)obj;
        grid.RowDefinitions.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)e.NewValue; i++)
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(
                new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

        //SetStarRows(grid);
    }

    #endregion

    #region ColumnCount Property

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified number of Columns to ColumnDefinitions. 
    /// Default Width is Auto
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ColumnCount", typeof(int), typeof(GridHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(-1, ColumnCountChanged));

    // Get
    public static int GetColumnCount(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(ColumnCountProperty);
    }

    // Set
    public static void SetColumnCount(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnCountProperty, value);
    }

    // Change Event - Add the Columns
    public static void ColumnCountChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(obj is Grid) || (int)e.NewValue < 0)
            return;

        Grid grid = (Grid)obj;
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)e.NewValue; i++)
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

        //SetStarColumns(grid);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I changed my class to derive from DependencyObject but I don't know what to do next. Should I replace my array with something like this:
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<BigInteger>> ?
I want to represent only this array so why should I use DependencyProperty instead of simple data types?

Comment: Binding only works with those objects that can notify their changes to the view, so data types should either raise an event when they change or be DependencyProperties to be able to automatically notify. you can use ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<BigInteger>> but there are simpler methods. take a look at the edit I've made to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be bound to DataGrid without extra work. One quick solution is to use DataTable instead of multi-dimentional  array:

```
<Window x:Class="StackExchange.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="myGrid"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public DataTable Macierz;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Macierz = new DataTable("Table");
    Macierz.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
    Macierz.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(int));
    Macierz.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(int));

    DataRow row1 = Macierz.NewRow();
    row1["Col1"] = 1;
    row1["Col2"] = 2;
    row1["Col3"] = 3;
    Macierz.Rows.Add(row1);

    DataRow row2 = Macierz.NewRow();
    row2["Col1"] = 4;
    row2["Col2"] = 5;
    row2["Col3"] = 6;
    Macierz.Rows.Add(row2);

    myGrid.DataContext = this;
    myGrid.ItemsSource = Macierz.DefaultView;
}
```